# character act 5 sphere online judge

Tags: c++

This is a coding problem from sphere online judge , i am not getting the right output for this code , and i kind of know why, just wanted to ask if using goto(x,y) would help correct the output for this problem. The position of the cusor after every loop is leading to the undesired output. can anybody suggest a way to correct that ?

Here's the probelm

**problem**

Using two characters: . (dot) and * (asterisk) print a grid-like pattern. The grid will have l lines, c columns, and each square shaped element of the grid will have the height and width equal to s.

Moreover, each of the grid elements will have a diagonal. The diagonal of the first square in the first line of the grid is directed towards down and right corner - use the \ (backslash) character to print it; while the next diagonal will be directed towards upper right corner - use the / (slash) character to print it. Print the successive diagonals alternately (please consult the example below).
Input

You are given t - the number of test cases and for each of the test case three positive integers: l - the number of lines, c - the number of columns in the grid and s - the size of the single square shaped element.
Output

For each of the test cases output the requested pattern (please have a look at the example). Use one line break in between successive patterns.

example
Input:
3
3 1 2 
4 4 1 
2 5 2

Output:

```
****
*\.*
*.\*
****
*./*
*/.*
****
*\.*
*.\*
****

*********
*\*/*\*/*
*********
*/*\*/*\*
*********
*\*/*\*/*
*********
*/*\*/*\*
*********

****************
*\.*./*\.*./*\.*
*.\*/.*.\*/.*.\*
****************
*./*\.*./*\.*./*
*/.*.\*/.*.\*/.*
****************
```

This is my code

```
 #include<iostream>
   using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int i,j,k,l,c,s,t;
  void basic(int,int,int);
     cin>>t;
      k=0;
     while(k<t)
     {
       cin>>l>>c>>s;
       for(i=1;i<=l;i++)
       {
         for(j=1;j<=c;j++)
         {
          basic(i,j,s); 
          }
          cout<<"\n";
       }

       k++;
     }
}


 void basic(int i,int j,int s)
 {
    int m,n,x,p,q;


    x=s+2;

    if(j==1)
        p=0;
       else
        p=1;

    if(i==1)
        q=0;    
     else   
        q=1;


        for(m=q;m<x;m++)
         {


           for(n=p;n<x;n++)
             {  

                if(m%(x-1)==0||n%(x-1)==0)
                  cout<<"*";
                else
                  {
                    if((i+j)%2==0)
                     {
                       if(m==n)
                         cout<<"\\";
                       else
                          cout<<".";
                     }

                     else
                     {
                        if((m+n)%(x-1)==0)
                          cout<<"/";
                         else
                           cout<<".";

                     }



                   }

             } 

             cout<<"\n";
         }



 }`
```

Comment: Using *what* `goto(x,y)`? Have you tried stepping through the code line by line in a debugger to see what it really does?

Comment: `goto(x,y)`  There is no such function in standard C++.

Comment: i think that every time the function is called and i print a small part of the grid the "\n" changes the line , i want the function to print the next square adjacent to the first one in the first line , so how can i shift the cursor s+2 steps upwords .

Comment: Moving the cursor around except by printing "normal" characters or e.g. using tabs, newline and carriage-return is non-standard. If you don't know the target system you can't use any non-standard functionality. So the only solution you can use is one that does each line from left to right, and one line at a time from top to bottom.

Comment: yeah exactly i thought about doing this and this is what i had done in previous problems similar to this one , but you see in this one i was having trouble finding a standard condition that'll help me print the diagonals easily , so then i thought about using a function , and it gets easier that way because you have a grid with index values on which it is simpler to apply conditions . but the main problem is shifting the cursor right next to where the first row of the first square in the first line ends.

Comment: @srishti77714 You could generate each line in memory, i.e. a `std::string`, and when done, just print that string.  No need messing around with cursor positions and such.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie like each line of the complete grid ?How to do that ?

Comment: @srishti77714 Yes.  You have the logic now.  The issue is that you're trying to write each character to the console immediately.  What you could do is just append the character to a string -- when that line is done, print the string in one shot.  Heck, you may be able to generate the entire pattern in a string that has newlines in it, and just output the whole thing at once with `cout << myString;`  Another approach is to create a 2d array, sized to the entire output.  Start it out empty, fill it in with the characters required, and just output the array, line by line.  Think outside the box.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i am not  familiar to doing things in memory first and then printing them on screen , if you could please tell what is it called in the technical terms so that i can see the syntax and everything , and update my self on this , it'll be great.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i too thought about the 2-d array but then the conditions for the diagonals is the problem even in that one as i suspect , because you can't apply i==j, and i+j==s+1 for all cases

Comment: @srishti77714 See here: http://ideone.com/N0EXmn  The first one is how you're doing things now.  The second is the way I am suggesting.

Comment: @srishti77714 *because you can't apply i==j, and i+j==s+1 for all cases*    -- Think of a 2d array as character cells.  Are you saying you can't determine what character goes where?  I know the logic may not be obvious now, but it *can* be done.  The only difference is that you're currently using the screen as your "grid".

Comment: i think i got it now , i'll try implementing it this way, thanks :)

Comment: @srishti77714  In addition, it is much easier to debug when you see a string being built character by character (when you use a debugger), then fiddling around with new lines, cursor positioning, etc.

Comment: @PaulMckenzie can you suggest some debuggers ? i haven't used any , i am a newbie.

Comment: Download any of the free compilers (Visual Studio Express, MingW via CodeBlocks, etc.) and build your program there.  Then use the debugger that comes with the compiler to step through your code.  Once done, then submit that program to the judge.  If you're just typing in code in the judge's text area and compiling, that is nothing more than a hope and a prayer way of getting this accomplished.